# Horizontal net force question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

A 1580kg car travels at 15m/s, what would the magnitude of the horizontal net force required to bring the car to a halt in 50m?

Comment: On this site, it's expected that askers show some effort in researching or solving whatever problem they have, and that they ask about a specific physics concept, rather than just "solve this homework problem please". So, what specific concept are you confused about in relation to this problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP shows no research effort whatsoever.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula $v_f^2 = v_i^2 + 2ad$ and note that $v_f = 0$ since the car is coming to a halt, then $v_f^2 = 2ad$. Here you are required to use $F=ma$ so the magnitude of the horizontal force is $ F = m\frac{v_f^2}{2d}$

Comment: Providing answers to questions like this one violates the spirit and intent of the forum.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the work done as 1/2 mv^2. (Kinetic energy )
This is the work done according to work energy theorem..
To calculate force divide this value(work) by displacement (50m)

Comment: Providing answers to questions like this one violates the spirit and intent of the forum.